# Php __get magic methods

Tags: php, oop

I'm new in PHP. In the Below code when I change private `$name` into public `$name` it don't displays name "Harry". I can't figure it out.

```
class Post{
public $name;
    public function __set($name,$value){
        echo $this->name=$value;
    }
}
$post=new Post;
$post->name="Harry";
```

Comment: what does this have to do with __get?

Answer (score 2):

Magic getters and setters are only used when the property doesn't exist or isn't accessible, this is called property overloading.

Since the `private $name` isn't accessible from outside of the class, it is using your magic setter.  Since `public $name` is accessible from outside of the class, it will just set that property's value.